# Persian/Arabic/Urdu poetry writing format?

Tags: arabic, poetry, persian

I have mainly seen three types of poetry writing formats in Urdu. I suppose, Urdu is similar to Persian and Arabic.

Examples of formats:

1. All verses centered. Single verse per line.

[image]

2. Two columns. Two verses per line (side by side).

[image]

3. Two columns. Single verse per line.

[image]

My question is simple: **Is there some formal terminology for describing these formats?**

Comment: The font style is called Nastaliq. I don't think left/right justification is anything unique. Also Arabic is not related to Urdu or Persian other than the script and a few loan words.

Comment: @AML Few loan words! 
Arabic loans words in Persian vocabulary approach 25 percent of a text in literature. According to another source, about 40% of everyday Persian literary vocabulary is of Arabic origin.
[Persian language Wikipedia. page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_language)

Comment: @Sami Depends on the level of formality and/or religiousness. Also Persian has their own native words for all those Arabic-based words, so really they could largely get by without them. For example, some secular Persian nationalists are even moving away from the Arabic-based Salaam in favor of the native Persian greeting Droud. Not everyone... but more now than in a long time. 25-40% these days seems a bit much, but we are getting off topic.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about learning or teaching languages. It may be on topic on [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/) but it appears to be too old to migrate.

Comment: What matters in poetry is the rhymes, not the writing format.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if literal translation of their name from Arabic to English makes sense

Vertical poetry  =  الشعر العمودي

Considered the purest form of poetry, the oldest and the classical way to write poetry.

Free form poetry or Free verse =  الشعر الحر 
no regulation as long as it rhythm, you can emphasize the pronunciation of a word, or even use silence to make it rhythm.
example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ1SqzSYvSQ

the writing style [single column or two columns] is not the main way of classification it is about following these rules

there is other types as well (which evolved later) however you only asked about theses

[image: Vertical poetry = الشعر العمودي]

[image: Free form poetry or Free verse]  =